# Trouble sending object with fetch

Tags: node.js, express, fetch

I am sending an object with fetch method from a webpage, that must then be appended to a json file on server. Here is how I am sending it:

```
fetch(url + '/send', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: {a: 1, b:2}
})
```

However, upon reading, all I get is an empty object.

When I send Body with Postman POST request, it works fine. Please help me find out why that is.

```
{
    "a":"1",
    "b": "2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the appropriate `Content-Type` header with your POST request:

```
fetch(url + '/send', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   body: {a: 1, b:2}
})
```